# Why does `${$(pwd)}` output current working directory in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

In zsh, `${$(pwd)}` output the current directory. However, if I run `echo ${/path/to/somewhere}`, it just shows an empty line. Why does this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume, you speak about `print ${$(pwd)}` or something like that, right?!*

The expansion of  `${$(pwd)}` to the current working directory is the expected behavior, although it might look strange at the first glance. Don't let you fool by thinking that the command substitution `$(pwd)` gets evaluated first an the result is used as a *variable name*... no, it is used as the *variable value*  as `man zshexpn` explains:

> `${name}`       The value, if any, of the parameter name is substituted.
>
> (...)
>    If a `${...}` type parameter expression or a `$(...)` type command
>   substitution is used in place of `name` above, it is expanded first
>          and the result is used as if it were the value of `name`.  (...) The form with `$(...)` is often useful in combination with the
>          flags described next; see the examples below.
>
> (...)
>   The flag f is useful to split a double-quoted substitution line by line.  For example, `${(f)"$(<file)"}` substitutes the contents
>          of file divided so that each line is an element of the resulting array.

To your second example. I think this is the pattern replace syntax:

> `${name/pattern/repl}`            Replace the longest possible match of pattern in the expansion of parameter name by string repl. (...)

See this example first:

```
$ foo=hello
$ print ${foo/hello/good/bye}
good/bye
```

If you omit `foo` you tell `zsh` to do a search and replace in the variable `${}`, which is empty:

```
$ print ${}

$
```

-- hence `${/something/foo/bar}` returns an empty string, too.